# ionic resources --icon windows not working

Tags: ionic2

ionic resources --icon windows

or

```
ionic resources windows
```

The above does not generate any icon or splashscreen resources for the Windows platform, rather it's generating for others.

How do I go about this as I can deploy the app with the default Cordova icon & splashscreen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`ionic prepare`** in windows to generate splash & icon in `res` folder and then you can copy from `res`to `resources\android` folder which will create icons and splashes in your next build of apk.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> During the build process, Cordova (v3.6 or later) will look through
>   the project’s config.xml file and copy the newly created resource
>   images to the platform’s specific resource folder. 
>   Android’s resource folder can be found in platforms/android/res, and
>   iOS uses platforms/ios/APP_NAME/Resources.

Windows isn't supported when it comes to automatically generate resources.

Comment: after building the default icon is showing in Android's platform/android/res folder, custom icon are not showing